# External Service: Not able to select correct Apex Class in Variable-Type "Apex-Defined"

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, callout, external-services

I create a flow in Salesforce and use the element `Action` to call an operation of an External Service. The External Service was created using an JSON OpenAPI Spec. 3 dynamic Apex Classes were created: `MyService`, `MyRequest` and `MyServiceOut`.

The GET operation work, so there is no issue with the external Service. The problem is the POST operation and its input parameter `body`. The POST operation has 2 input parameters: `id` and `body`. `Body` is of type `MyRequest`. `MyRequest` has a getter and setter for the attribute `properties` which is of type `Map<String, Object>`. To set the `body` in the flow element, I create a new resource of type `Variable` and set the data type `Apex-defined` and then want to select the correct Apex class: `MyRequest`. However, this Apex class is not displayed in the selection, although the Apex classes were created automatically when the External Service was created and the operations were activated. What do I have to do so that the class is displayed?

I have already deleted and recreated the External Service several times. Unfortunately, this has not helped. Does anyone have any idea why this could be?